# Strange behavior of Visual Studio preprocessor

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, c++-cli, preprocessor

I'm currently working on VS2013 Community with C++/CLI. I wanted to do there some cross-platform abstract class, and to be smart enough I wrote header like this:

```
#ifndef SOMECLASS_H
#define SOMECLASS_H

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define PUBLIC_INTERFACE public interface
#else
#define PUBLIC_INTERFACE
#endif

PUBLIC_INTERFACE class SomeClass {
public:
    virtual int DummyMethod(void) = 0;
};

#endif // SOMECLASS_H
```

The problem is with macro PUBLIC_INTERFACE which should on MS compiler gave me "public interface class" after preprocessor work done. Unfortunatelle what I have is "public struct class". Why?
I was thinking that it is some special case and preprocessor want to do some special magic (I'm no an expert with managed C++), and I wrote:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
public interface class SomeClass {
#else
class SomeClass {
#endif
public:
    virtual int DummyMethod(void) = 0;
};
```

But in this case everything works fine and preprocessor yields me "public interface class". What is the reason of translating "interface" keyword in macro to "struct" keyword. Am I doing something wrong or this is some issue of MS preprocessor?

Comment: There is a macro named `interface` in the Windows SDK.  You need to beef up yours with `#if defined(_MSC_VER) && defined(_M_CEE)`

Comment: Yes, but why `interface` isn't replaced with `struct` in a second part of code that I wrote, keep in mind that it is as a replacement of the first `SomeClass` declaration, so `#include <windows.h>` is also above that declaration?

Comment: `interface` is only replaced with `struct` when used in macro.